# How to get int data from iphone sqlite data base

Tags: iphone, xcode, sqlite

I am getting data from iphone sqlite like this. I have 6 records in the table.

My table has fields responses_Id, participant_Id, answer_option, answer_text, update_date_time only all are varchar fields except responses_Id and participant_Id)

```
    + (void) getInitialDataToDisplay:(NSString *)dbPath {

CereniaAppDelegate *appDelegate = (CereniaAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

    const char *sql = "select * from survey_question_responses";
    sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

        while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {

            NSInteger primaryKey = sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt, 0);
            Coffee *coffeeObj = [[Coffee alloc] initWithPrimaryKey:primaryKey];
                            coffeeObj.participant_Id=(This is integerin table)
            coffeeObj.answer_option = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 2)];
            coffeeObj.answer_option = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 3)];
            coffeeObj.answer_option = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 4)];
            coffeeObj.answer_option = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 5)];

            NSString*test=coffeeObj.answer_option;



            [appDelegate.coffeeArray addObject:coffeeObj];

            int count=[appDelegate.coffeeArray count];

            NSLog(test);
            NSLog(@"count is %d",count);


            [coffeeObj release];
        }
    }
    }
else
    sqlite3_close(database); //Even though the open call failed, close the database connection to release all the memory.
  }
```

When I NSlog data it does not show any things.

Comment: Is it showing count is=0 ? is it going up to the log statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into the [SQLite Documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html). All result values from queries are defined there.
You can use `sqlite3_column_int` for Integers similar to `sqlite3_column_text` for Text

Answer (score 2):

```
NSNumber *primaryKey = [NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt, 0)];
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit on this for the OP? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
while(sqlite3_step(selectAllStmt) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            NSLog(@"record found");
            char *temp = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectAllStmt, 0);
            if (temp!=nil) {
                intId=[[NSString stringWithUTF8String:temp] intValue];
            }
            temp =NULL;
            // [pool release];
        }

+ (void) getInitialDataToDisplay:(NSString *)dbPath {

CereniaAppDelegate *appDelegate = (CereniaAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

    const char *sql = "select * from survey_question_responses";
    sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

        while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {
    NSInteger primaryKey;
NSInteger intparticipant_Id;


            char *temp = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 0);
            if (temp!=nil) {
                primaryKey=[[NSString stringWithUTF8String:temp] intValue];
            }
            temp =NULL;
            Coffee *coffeeObj = [[Coffee alloc] initWithPrimaryKey:primaryKey];


temp = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 1);
            if (temp!=nil) {
                intparticipant_Id=[[NSString stringWithUTF8String:temp] intValue];
            }
            temp =NULL;
                            coffeeObj.participant_Id=intparticipant_Id;

            coffeeObj.answer_option = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 2)];
            coffeeObj.answer_option = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 3)];
            coffeeObj.answer_option = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 4)];
            coffeeObj.answer_option = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 5)];

            NSString*test=coffeeObj.answer_option;



            [appDelegate.coffeeArray addObject:coffeeObj];

            int count=[appDelegate.coffeeArray count];

            NSLog(test);
            NSLog(@"count is %d",count);


            [coffeeObj release];
        }
    }
    }
else
    sqlite3_close(database); //Even though the open call failed, close the database connection to release all the memory.
  }


Note:- char *temp = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectAllStmt, 0);
            if(temp != NULL)
                str = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:temp];
            else
                str = @"";
            temp =NULL;

If you want to take integer then you can do type casting "str = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:temp];" here......
```